# HTML table cell splitted in slots that should take the full cell height

Tags: jquery, css, html-table, cell

I am using a table in a way that each  cell is split in one or more slot as shown in the following JS Bin.

[table demo](http://live.datatables.net/pejeseho/2/edit)

What I would like to get is that each cell is fully filled by the existing slots, e.g.
- the red slot should fill up to 100% the cell height
- each of the the brown and the violet slot should fill 50% of the cell height
And the cell filling should automatically adapt if slots are removed or added, e.g. if the yellow slot is removed each of the remaining blue e orange slots should fill 50% of the cell height 
I digged a lot on the web but I did not find any viable solution. 
Any suggestion?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with css add a default height for the cell and include classes for full-height, half-height and triple-hight... etc

```
td,
.full-cell {
  padding: 0 !important;
  height: 70px;
}

.half-cell{
      height: 35px;
}

.triple-cell{
      height: 23.333333333333333px;
}
```

Here's a workaround
http://live.datatables.net/pejeseho/7/

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for a CSS solution, without the need to use JS to apply different classes to the cells in the case some slots are removed or added.